# how to use JRSwapFileVirtualizer for jasper reports in java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

how to use JRSwapFileVirtualizer for jasper reports in java, this is the code which i use..

```java
JRSwapFileVirtualizer virtualizer = null;
virtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(10000, new JRSwapFile("F://", 1000, 1000), false);
param.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);

xmlDataSource = new JRXmlDataSource(reportFile,"/table/tr");
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperpath, param, xmlDataSource);
```

still i get the heap space error(OutOfMemeoryException), and the file which gets created is empty.

Comment: Didn't you already ask a nearly identical question? Either post the answer to that question yourself or wait until someone answers. Don't flood the page with multiple question on the same problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First parameter of the constructor of the JRSwapFileVirtualizer is the maximum number of report pages that will be stored in primary memory (RAM) before sections of the report are stored in virtual memory (disk). So if your report page size does not exceed 10000 page then you are not able to store them in virtual memory and even though you write the virtualizer code you are not actually using this beauty.

Try something like,

```
JRSwapFileVirtualizer virtualizer = null; 
virtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(3, new JRSwapFile("F://", 2048, 1024), false); 
param.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);
```

Hope it works :-)

cheers...

Comment: When i use this code it's work fine. Problem is when i create the report in xls format with 40000 record it will give me a error of heap memory.

Comment: "F://" is the path where your jasper is ? or where your excel was generated?